# Issue with Java path when running Gradle

Tags: path, gradle, java-home

As the title says, I am running into an issue with JAVA_HOME when I try to run gradle from the cmd line.

I've downloaded the bin.zip file, which is stored at c:/Gradle/gradle-2.2.1

I then run the 'gradle' command from terminal and am greeted with the following message
"Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation."

Both my JAVA_HOME and Path files are correct, for java. I've added the Gradle bin to the path variable also.

The tutorial I am following is found here:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was solved in removing the ';' from the end of my JAVA_HOME variable..